# GCP 500 Erroring despite files uploaded

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a React app for the first time and can't seem to figure out why it is not working...

Here is what I have tried:

```
git clone [repo url]
cd repo/client
npm i
npm build
cd build
vim app.yaml
```

Entered the following:

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs12
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/.*
```

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --verbosity=debug
```

Output:

```
INFO: Manifest: [{'index.html': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.reactfrontend-336116.appspot.com/226a7f7ca6cf647c5457b709cef629bb950fbc9a', 'sha1Sum': '226a7f7ca6cf647c5457b709cef629bb950fbc9a'}, '961.index.bundle.js': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.reactfrontend-336116.appspot.com/907d0e7384a3b3060ba5b0bf522d5c6e99f38d39', 'sha1Sum': '907d0e7384a3b3060ba5b0bf522d5c6e99f38d39'}, '1': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.reactfrontend-336116.appspot.com/12de9963495774159595601cd57e64c1febb1e9a', 'sha1Sum': '12de9963495774159595601cd57e64c1febb1e9a'}, 'app.yaml': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.reactfrontend-336116.appspot.com/e3979db38f5ace413d6dff3d8f7e30bda5922438', 'sha1Sum': 'e3979db38f5ace413d6dff3d8f7e30bda5922438'}, 'index.bundle.js.LICENSE.txt': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.reactfrontend-336116.appspot.com/e74ccdb144d7d0ada75f8115a86b4c93444238cf', 'sha1Sum': 'e74ccdb144d7d0ada75f8115a86b4c93444238cf'}, 'index.bundle.js': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.reactfrontend-336116.appspot.com/4bca86ed5f442588b4cd5a7dc59719afe5c67015', 'sha1Sum': '4bca86ed5f442588b4cd5a7dc59719afe5c67015'}, 'source-context.json': {'sourceUrl': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.reactfrontend-336116.appspot.com/a0d08448a753f65abae14090837cf7c12a173cad', 'sha1Sum': 'a0d08448a753f65abae14090837cf7c12a173cad'}}]
```

As you can see the all files are correctly uploaded (there are no assets), but when I access the URL I get a 500 Server error: "The server encountered an error and could not complete your request."

I'm not really sure what I've done wrong... I can run the React app locally without any issues

Webpack:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// hot reload CSS:
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.bundle.js',
    assetModuleFilename: 'images/[hash][ext][query]'
  },
  target: 'web',
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    port: 3000
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        type: 'asset/inline'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' })]
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```  - url: /.*    ```

Comment: Same thing, ended up deploying to AWS instead